# HTC ONE X (4.0.3)..Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

what is the correct emulator for the **HTC ONE X (4.0.3)..**.

I create the emulator by giving its resolution for **htc one x** but its create some **UI** problem.

My emulator's resolution is **720*1280**, screen sixe is **4.7 inches** exactly with comapare to **HTC ONE X**...in my emulator there is no problem with UI, But in the real device its create some problem in UI.

. I Used same android version **(android 4.0.3)**  in both emulator and real devices...I create the FOLDER for this  is **LAYOUT-NORMAL-XHDPI** in **RES** folder.

Is that any **ONLINE EMULATOR** available for **HTC ONE X**...????

Answer (score 0):

> try **layout-sw360dp**
>
> if you want to different layout for both landscape mode and portrait
>   mode, you can use
>
> **layout-sw360dp-port**
>
> **layout-sw360dp-land**

Comment: Do you use dp or px when you define the layout values? use dp instead of px.